# HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error using WCF Data service Authentication

Tags: wcf, wcf-data-services

I'm following this tutorial http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astoriateam/archive/2010/07/21/odata-and-authentication-part-6-custom-basic-authentication.aspx.
I need to add to the web.config :

```
<system.webServer> 
  <modules> 
    <add name="BasicAuthenticationModule" 
         type="SimpleService.BasicAuthenticationModule"/> 
  </modules> 
</system.webServer>
```

But I get Cannot add duplicate collection entry of type 'add' with unique key attribute 'name' set to 'BasicAuthenticationModule'
So, I search the net for some solution, many posts suggest adding this line

```
<system.webServer> 
      <modules> 
        <remove name="BasicAuthenticationModule"/>
        <add name="BasicAuthenticationModule" 
             type="SimpleService.BasicAuthenticationModule"/> 
      </modules> 
    </system.webServer>
```

but now I get a "Lock Violation"

any help please??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, It's kind of disappeared and everything works great now.
At first I had to disable all Authentication for the Application in the IIS, but I had to do a system restore, after that it's all history.
Sorry I can't help .